# How do I enable spell check feature in HTML text area?

Tags: html, coldfusion, spell-checking

I want to enable spell check feature in HTML text areas. I am using ColdFusion. Is this possible?

Comment: If the browser supports it and the user has it enabled, it will spellcheck. My browser spellchecks everything, always.

Comment: As animuson says, leave it to the user if they want it. Also, ColdFusion is server-side technology, so will not itself do spell checking on the client-side (though there may be some CF-based widgets that output JavaScript that can do it).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have used [Foundeo's spell checker](http://foundeo.com/spell-checker/) before. Very easy to integrate and customise.

Answer (score 7):

You could try to enable native spellcheck support for input forms, like this:

```
<input type="text" size="50" spellcheck="true">
<textarea spellcheck="true"></textarea>
```

You can also designate a correct language dictionary to use. If not specified, the browser's default language dictionary will be used. You can override browser defaults by specifying the `lang` attribute .

```
<input type="text" spellcheck="true" lang="en">
```

Answer (score 1):

The browser will automatically spell check if it supports that feature. For JavaScript based spell checking, see here:
http://www.javascriptspellcheck.com/

-Sunjay

Answer (score 0):

If using React, you have to capitalize the `c`:

`spellCheck='true'`